# Big difference on file size between iOS picture on the local and on server

Tags: ios, iphone, image, ios7

There is a image URL `http://example.com/xxoo.jpg`

1. Open this URL from Chrome, save image to desktop to check the image file size.
2. Open this URL from iPhone safari, save image to camera roll, than send it to computer to check the image file size.
3. Save the image in my iOS app by using `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum`, and than send it to computer to check the image file size.

Strangely, these files are all different from each other. The difference can be hundreds of kb.

I had tried download image by using `AFNetworking setImageWithURL`, `SDImageView setImageWithURL`, `SDImageDownloader downloadImageWithURL` and `dataWithContentsOfURL`. These downloads are the same size but different from the size on the server.

There is an example code:

```
    [[SDWebImageDownloader sharedDownloader] downloadImageWithURL:imageURL
 options:0 progress:^(NSInteger receivedSize, NSInteger expectedSize) {

    } completed:^(UIImage *image, NSData *data, NSError *error, BOOL finished) {
        _imageToBeDownload = image;
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
    }];
```

Comment: Do you have a question? Does it cause you a problem?

Comment: @Wain Yes, I want to know why these are different size. And I want the image has the same file size as it on server.

Answer (score 1):

These are the possible reasons:

- The camera roll may use a different file format than the original file format on the server.
- `SDWebImageDownloader`returns an *image* not a `NSData`object containing the JPEG file from the server. When saving an image with `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` the file format can be different than that on the server.
- Proxies in the Internet per default are allowed to convert the media types (in particular images) to a different one, possibly with a higher compression level in order to save space in the cache. So, a GET request may return a cached version of the original file on the server which has lower resolution. (Reference: [14.9.5 No-Transform Directive, RFC 2616](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9.5))

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the image file format is the same as it's on server.

Comment: @jacky It's very unlikely that two different software applications happen to produce absolutely the same image file for the same image, especially if the routine producing the output file has no knowledge what the original file was ;)